# Download Streamed gif file and store in byte array

Tags: android, inputstream, gif

I am building an android app where I need to down load a gif image from a URL and store in a byte array. Been using bitmap factory classes but it keeps returning null.  I am storing the byte array to sqlite  then retrieving and displaying.

```
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();


        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //We create an array of bytes
        byte[] data = new byte[4094];
        int current = 0;

        while((current = bis.read(data,0,data.length)) != -1){
            buffer.write(data,0,current);
        }
```

I have even tried to convert using the Bitmap.Factory, but returns nulls.

Answer (score 0):

ok after a bit googling i got this to work.

```
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();


        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        byte[] img = new byte[5000];

        int current = 0;


        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write( current);
        }



        forecastJsonStr = baos.toByteArray();
```